# Object layout differs from error for int, but not for float class child

Tags: python, class, floating-point, integer

I'm struggling to understand the difference between `int` and `float` child classes in the next behavior:

```
class MyIntOne(int):
    pass

class MyIntTwo(int):
    pass

a = MyIntOne(1)

a.__class__ = MyIntTwo
```

Results in:
`TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'MyIntTwo' object layout differs from 'MyIntOne'`

While all the same for `float` does not throw any errors:

```
class MyFloatOne(float):
    pass

class MyFloatTwo(float):
    pass

b = MyFloat1(1.5)
b.__class__ = MyFloatTwo
```

I know I can fix it by setting `__slots__` attribute for `int`, but `float` works fine even without it, what am I missing here?

Comment: what you are missing is that what you are doing will result in undefined behavior. That you can find a hack to make it work doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: It's just a minimal repro for the illustration, the main code is more specific and meaningful of course, so I just wanted to generalise it a little. What do you mean by undefined behavior?